# Schedule jasper report using quartz scheduler

Tags: java, jasper-reports, quartz-scheduler

I am using the quartz for creating the schedule and run the job. However, I need to generate and send the jasper report in one of the job. I know that jasper server can be used to schedule the report but I have scheduled created in my java application. How can one create the report using java application.

I read through the link - [Jasper Report scheduler](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-community-project-installation-guide/v610/configuring)

In short how do one ask jasper server to create the report and let quartz job send an email to given user.

```
public class MyJob implements Job {

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

    System.out.println("Context : " + context.toString());

  //Can we create the jasper report here and then send using email, I have jasper server but I wanted to use the separate job to process the report and send. 

 }
```

Comment: If you need do this job separately from JasperServer you must add `.jasper` or `.jrxml` file from your Server's report to application and then call it from Quartz job.

Comment: If you just need to call it from job but not separately you can call report from JasperServer via REST API and then do ahything you want in Quartz job.

Comment: OK. How can one integrate the quartz scheduler in Jasper server. I have already created the multiple  scheduler  and multiple jobs. Now I need to send the Jasper report using the job scheduled. Since you mentioned that I can do it using separate instance then how do we let Jasper server knows my schedule and invoke the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access you JasperServer via REST API and do the rest of job in the Quarz scheduler.
1) Start Quartz job.
2) Authenticate on Jasper Server ([here is documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/login-service))
3) Call the report via REST API ([documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/running-report))
4) Get the result and do anything you want (e.g. sent to email).
5) End Quartz job.